# Can I import just one declaration from an F# module?

Tags: module, f#

Suppose I have a module like this:

```
module Foo

let x = 1
let y = 2
```

Now I can use this module like this:

```
module Bar

let z = Foo.x + Foo.y
```

Is it possible to import a definition from `Foo` such that it does not need to be qualified?

Something like:

```
module Bar

import x from Foo // Not real code

let z = x + Foo.y // x need not be qualified
```

Note that I do not want to import *everything* from `Foo`

Comment: I would try "let x = Foo.x"

Comment: @Foole That would work... although it requires me to write `x` twice and it only allows one import per line... compare this to ES6: `import { x, y, z } from 'Foo'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot, there is no direct F# equivalent to the ES6 `import { ... } from 'Module'` syntax.  F# supports organizing code into both modules and namespaces, but both modules and namespaces are 'imported' in their entirety with the `open` keyword.  As mentioned in the comments, you can use local bindings to simplify qualified access to values (such as `let exchangeRange = Conversions.Currency.UsdToCadExchangeRate`) or type aliases to simplify qualified access to types (`type Converter = Conversions.Currency.CurrencyConverter`).

In addition, modules can be marked with the `[<AutoOpen>]` attribute to make their contents accessible without qualified access, or the `[<RequireQualifiedAccess>]` attribute to make their contents accessible *only* when qualified, even if the module is referenced in an `open` expression.

See [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/import-declarations-the-open-keyword) for more information.